# Save length of a string in a variable or use when needed?

Tags: python, performance

The question is about code speed and efficiency, I know it does not matter but I am curious. Which of the two is *faster* and better to use? Keeping the length of the string in the variable takes memory, but on the other hand calculating each time the length of the string also takes time, so which is better?

```
my_str = "Hello, World!"
strlen = len(my_str)

print(f"Length of str is: {strlen}")
print(f"Length of str is: {strlen}")
print(f"Length of str is: {strlen}")
print(f"Length of str is: {strlen}")
```

```
my_str = "Hello, World!"
print(f"Length of str is: {len(my_str)}")
print(f"Length of str is: {len(my_str)}")
print(f"Length of str is: {len(my_str)}")
print(f"Length of str is: {len(my_str)}")
```

Comment: "Keeping the length of the string in the variable takes memory," no, not really. The length of a string is already cached by the `str` object

Comment: Specific timings are likely specific to your environment: use `timeit` and find out for yourself. https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#module-timeit

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are you sure? Any source?

Comment: https://tio.run/##bY29DsMgDIR3P4XLAkgsSefsfYOOXQoNEn8Cd4hQnp1aokulLpZ9352vHLTndB3D1RyRfLSe0MeSK30vgHg8GlXcUNxsCNngPdfwvAhgNdjEgKeaLg1ACyszq4Tj3cnOhhftpxQGm6V32ZyYEuM@35xCA61/o6rpn2hjIvssZMCdpfpEihaDtOoxPg

Comment: Are you familiar with time complexity and location complexity? Those are two different ways to measure a program. In your case it's obviously negligible, but in general it depends on what you are trying to achieve and what are your bottlenecks.

Comment: calling len is slower than storing its result, but now you have 2 variables. What if my_str changes? you have to update strlen too.

Comment: @ProAssemblyProgrammer yes, why would you think otherwise? Essentially *all* built-in Python objects will maintain their size, `len` for containers is *never* linear. But if you are skeptical, [here is the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a33f2c2bae759fc9d06e1c032fd2026135f2df45/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12636), note, it essentially calls [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a33f2c2bae759fc9d06e1c032fd2026135f2df45/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L140) which just accesses the `-> length` field.

Comment: Note, Python, internally, uses various structs to handle `str` objects, depending on the specifics of the unicode code points it contains, but here are the type definitions: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/680254a8dc64e3ada00f88a7c42d41eb02108353/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h#L85

Answer (score 0):

I think that in almost any imaginable circumstances, the memory footprint of storing the length of a single string should not matter.

In most cases the author of code should optimize for clarity, rather than speed, unless it is a proven bottleneck.

Comment: couldn't agree more with: "_optimize for clarity, [...] unless it is a proven bottleneck._"

Answer (score -1):

Every function call in Python is relatively expensive -- just the mechanism to do the call, no matter whether it does any work in the function then.

So your first option is faster.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Data_Aggregation says "Function call overhead in Python is relatively high, especially compared with the execution speed of a builtin function."

Answer (score -2):

Since computers currently have a lot of memory and the value of an integer is practically insignificant, I would go the first way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well actually I don't know how the string object is constructed in python or how len() acts on it ... So I'd rather not risk it and save the value to a variable. But maybe you are absolutely right.